# setTimeout() function being called twice in a row

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a bot that sends alerts at variable intervals. I am using setTimeout() and I have an issue I can't seem to be able to figure out. The (simplified) code is:

```
//Original call to setTimeout():

timeout = setTimeout(issueAlarm, 2147483647); // highest possible interval setTimeout() will accept. 

//In bot:
// dh is a priority queue that keeps timestamps sorted from smaller to larger as the user requests alerts. 
//'mom' is a moment.js variable that holds the most recent request. 
//This block of code checks the PQ and if what the user just entered is smaller than what is already stored, it updates the timeout. 
//This seems to work fine
// First get input from user and store the desired time of first alert in 'mom'. Then:
var nextD = dh.peekNext();
if (nextD.timestamp >= mom.valueOf() ){
    var now = new Date();        
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = mom.valueOf() - now;
    setTimeout(issueAlarm, timeout);
    }

//issueAlarm function:

function issueAlarm() {
    var next = dh.getNext(); // this pops the first alarm from the queue
    // here goes some code that issues message. Then:
    var peek = dh.peekNext(); // this looks at the next element in the queue without popping it
    if (peek) {
        var now = new Date();
        timeout = peek.timestamp - now;
        setTimeout(issueAlarm, timeout);
        }
    }
```

The example inputs are:
First input entered: Set an alert every 8 hours starting 5 minutes from now ("call Bob")

Second input entered: Set an alert every 8 hours starting 4 minutes from now ("call Jane")

In 4 minutes, i correctly get "call Jane" (this one gets set from the bot code)
One minute later, I correctly get "call Bob", but also i get "call Jane" (which should not happen until 8 hours later)

I printed all the timeout values and they seem correct. I also am printing the return of the setTimeout() function inside the issueAlarm() function.

Inside the first call: _idleTimeout: 59994 (this is correct, the next call is in one minute)

Inside the second call: _idleTimeout: 28739994 (this looks correct, it's approximately 8 hours, but still i get a third call right away)

Inside the third call: _idleTimeout: 28799991 (this timeout looks correct but this function call shouldn't have happened)

I'm using botFramework. My knowledge of JavaScript and node.js is far from extensive. I have printed out everything I could think of, but I can't figure out why that third call is being made right away.

This happens only if the first input entered requests an alert that starts later than the one entered in the second input. But I can't possibly understand why.

Comment: What is purpose of changing reference of `timeout` from `setTimeout` to `timeout = mom.valueOf() - now;` and `timeout = peek.timestamp - now;`?

Comment: You are not clearing the timeout in issueAlarm, before setting a new one, if that matters. Also, are you sure about the timeout interval values that you are issuing for the timeouts, could they be shorter than you think?

Comment: @Piwwoli: I have tried clearing the timeout. It didn't work. I am printing here the intervals that are returned from the setTimeout function. And as i said, i've also printed the values before passing them to the function. They are correct

Comment: @guest271314 : that's how I change the intervals. I use the 'timeout' variable initially so that i can clear the interval timeout when a user enters the time they want their alert. Then, inside issueAlarm() i could just call: setTimeout(issueAlarm, peek.timestamp-now) instead of passing it to timeout (also tried a local variable), but i kept it like this because it's easier to debug

Comment: Is `clearTimeout()` called at most once?

Comment: @guest271314 : Not in the case the second input is to be scheduled earlier than the first one (the case in which it doesn't work). Why?

Comment: @guest271314 : Not sure why you asked that, but eventually, after thinking a lot of why it worked if i called it only once, i figured out the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Please remove "SOLVED" from your title and "The solution is at the bottom" from your question. An answer to a question is supposed to be put in the large box labeled "Your Answer", not inside the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I thought you could have a problem with the Next function that returns you the data, take a look to my example. If your function is returning the next element as they were saved, you could not use that function, you need to build a function that return the first alarm to call. Hope it helps!

```js
var dh = {};
dh.alarms = [{time: 1000, name:"Jane"},{time:5000, name:"Jane"},{time: 3000, name:"Bob"}];

dh.first = function(){
dh.alarms = dh.alarms.sort(function(a,b){return a.time - b.time});
next = dh.alarms.slice(0,1);
dh.alarms = dh.alarms.slice(1);
return next[0]
}

dh.next = function(){
next = dh.alarms.slice(0,1);
dh.alarms = dh.alarms.slice(1);
return next[0]
}

var timeout = setTimeout(executeAlarm, 2999999);

function start(){
    
  var next = dh.first(); // dh.next(); I thought this is your problem!!
  if(next && next.name){

    clearInterval(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){executeAlarm(next)},next.time);
  }
  
}

function executeAlarm(next){
  if(!next || !next.name) clearInterval(timeout)
  document.getElementById("alarms").innerHTML += "<span> Alarm for " + next.name + "</span>";
  start();
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", start, false );
```

```html
<div id="alarms"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as i said (and the returned values from setTimeout() show), the elements are retrieved correctly. The alarms are stored in a priority queue and, therefore, the first element is always the smallest (think a min heap and the elements are correctly sorted). Also, the 3rd alarm runs immediately after the second
As i was intrigued by one of the comments above, and I'm calling clearTimeout() only once in the bot code (instead of calling it every time a new "smaller" element was added). That seems to work, but i still don't know why and I can't really use it.

Comment: Take a look in your code flow is like this:

1- ClearInterval and setTimeout in 1 minute (Jane)
2- Call from setTimeout to 1 Minute (Bob)
3- Right away Jane alarm is fired again.

It's because you are not cleaning the first timeout. If you see in my code I clearInterval every time I call start function.

Comment: As i said in one of the comments above, i have tried using clearTimeout() in the body of issueAlarm and nothing changed. 
Anyway, there's no need to clear the timeout once the function has been called, only when the function hasn't been called yet and you want to change it, which is what i do in the bot code.
Calling clearTimeout() only once in the bot code is the only thing that has changed anything.

Comment: Figured it out! It was related to clearing the Timeout, but not in the function itself, but up in the bot code. Updated the question with my findings, thanks a lot for taking the time (and because it was while making sure clearTimeout() wasn't fully necessary in the main function, that i realized the issu. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figure it out! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The problem was here, in the bot code:

```
if (nextD.timestamp >= mom.valueOf() ){
        var now = new Date();        
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = mom.valueOf() - now;
        setTimeout(issueAlarm, timeout);
        }
```

I was clearing the timeout correctly the first time (when i cleared the original timeout of 2^31 - 1), but not afterwards. The issue is that the line in which i call setTimeout should be

```
timeout = setTimeout(issueAlarm, timeout);
```

So that the return is stored in a timeout object. I was making subsequent calls to clearTimeout() by passing a value, not an object, and therefore the timeout stored first (5 minutes, 'call Bob') was never cleared.

Thanks to @guest271314 and to @damianfabian for helping me get to the correct answer.